# How to stop divs from overlapping? (it works fine in browser, but not on phones or tablets)

Tags: android, jquery, css, html

I was asked to make an ebay template for somebody, and with some help, and a lot of half-assing, I got it to do what I needed it to do. Before I even show the code, I'm just going to warn you that it's really a bad code, but it does what it needs to. However, when the template is viewed on phones or tablets, there is one minor problem, and it's a set of 3 divs that overlap.

Here is what it looks like:
http://i1373.photobucket.com/albums/ag383/Dixie_Stockwell/Templatepic_zpsdf572b2e.png

The table in the middle has three columns overlapped, as you can see. How can I fix this?

Here is the code for that area:

```
<div style="border:2px solid white;width:700px;height:350px;overflow:scroll;overflow-         y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;background-color:#90C382;">
  <u><b><font color=#EC008B><font     size=5>MEASUREMENTS IN INCHES</u></b></font color=#EC008B></font size=5>
  <br>
  <div style="margin-left:-450px;width:233px;height:350px;background-color:#90C382;"><br><br>&emsp;    
    <u><b>TOPS/DRESSES</u></b><br><br>&emsp;

MEASUREMENTS

  </div>
  <div style="margin-top:-348px; margin-left:0px;width:233px;height:350px;background-color:#90C382;"><br><br>&emsp;
  <u><b>BOTTOMS</u> </b><br><br>&emsp;

MEASUREMENTS

  </div>
  <div style="margin-top:-352px;margin-left:448px;width:233px;height:350px;background-color:#90C382;"><br>
    <img src="http://i1373.photobucket.com/albums/ag383/Dixie_Stockwell/Measurementstraced-01_zpsca8e6a7c.png" width="200px" height="298.5px" align="right";>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why u no use external stylesheet?

Comment: It would be cool if you indented your code, nobody wants to ready code in one big long line.

Comment: I really don't know what I'm doing. :l I'm pretty bad at this stuff, in all honesty. I really do apologize for the atrocity that I call coding.

Comment: Thats okay, everyone was a bad coder at some point. But inline styles are pretty much a no-no. You should consider going thru some free css tutorials.

Comment: I probably should. =p

Comment: Thank you for the tips and suggestions. I still need to know if there is an easy fix, I've only been working on code for about 2 weeks, and this should be my only project I need to do for my work, and I just need to fix the overlapping problem. In the description the picture of the problem is still there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might try using "float" rather than the negative margins, here's a great blog post with more details about how floats work: [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/). Also, if you're only having this problem in your handheld devices, you could specify separate rules for those devices. More about that here: [Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/). Not my blog but Chris Coyier explains things very well, helped me a lot when I was learning. Good luck!